# HighCharts to support RTL

Tags: c#, highcharts, right-to-left, dotnethighcharts

Highcharts does not support rtl be default.
When placing rtl texts like hebrew/arabic the text is completely destroyed, making it sometimes unreadable.
How do I configure HighCharts to support RTL?

I am using the dotnetHighCharts if it helps...

Answer (score 14):

try this code:
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/buYCZ/)

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    style:{
    direction: 'rtl'
    },
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'column'
},

xAxis: {
    categories: [
         ' تست a', 
        'حسن', 
        'كريم', 
        'محمود'
    ],
    reversed: true
},

yAxis: {

    labels: {
         useHTML: true,
            format: '{value} متر مربع'
        },
    title: {
        text: 'الاسم الأول',
        useHTML: true
    },
},
title: {
    text: 'تست a',
   useHTML: true
},

legend: {
    useHTML: true
},    

tooltip: {
   useHTML: true

},

series: [{
    name: 'تست',
    data: [10000,30000,20000,40000]

}]});
```

Answer (score 12):

Just add `useHTML: true` to plot options of your chart.
See demo here [jsfiddle.net/3me9h7k2](http://jsfiddle.net/3me9h7k2)

or

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'container',
    type: 'pie'
},

title: {
    text: 'یک نمودار؟!',
    useHTML: true, //bug fixed `IE9` and `EDGE`
    style: {
        fontSize: '20px',
        fontFamily: 'tahoma',
        direction: 'rtl',
    },
},

tooltip: {
    useHTML: true,
    style: {
        fontSize: '20px',
        fontFamily: 'tahoma',
        direction: 'rtl',
    },
},

plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            y: -5, //Optional
            format: '\u202B' + '{point.name}', // \u202B is RLE char for RTL support
            style: {
                fontSize: '15px',
                fontFamily: 'tahoma',
                textShadow: false, //bug fixed IE9 and EDGE
            },
            useHTML: true,
        },
        //showInLegend: true,
    },
},

series: [{
    name: 'برند',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'اینترنت اکسپلورر؟!',
        y: 56.33
    }, {
        name: 'کروم؟!',
        y: 24.03,
    }, {
        name: 'فایرفکس؟!',
        y: 10.38
    }, {
        name: 'سفاری؟!',
        y: 4.77
    }, {
        name: 'اوپرا؟!',
        y: 0.91
    }, {
        name: 'دیگر؟!',
        y: 0.2
    }],
}],
```

});

Answer (score 5):

I think, this may be helpful:

- [legend rtl](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.rtl)
- [tooltip useHTML for rtl](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML)

In general, useHTML for all labels etc. is recommended.

Answer (score 3):

You can use of a [`RLE` (Start of right-to-left embedding)](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-bidi-unicode-controls#basedirection) control character in text. be like this:

```
format: '\u202B' + '{point.name}'
```

Sample code:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'یک نمودار؟!',
        useHTML: true, //bug fixed `IE9` and `EDGE`
        style: {
            fontSize: '20px',
            fontFamily: 'tahoma',
            direction: 'rtl',
        },
    },

    tooltip: {
        useHTML: true,
        style: {
            fontSize: '20px',
            fontFamily: 'tahoma',
            direction: 'rtl',
        },
    },

    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            cursor: 'pointer',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                y: -5, //Optional
                format: '\u202B' + '{point.name}', // \u202B is RLE char for RTL support
                style: {
                    fontSize: '15px',
                    fontFamily: 'tahoma',
                    textShadow: false, //bug fixed IE9 and EDGE
                },
            },
        },
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'برند',
        colorByPoint: true,
        data: [{
            name: 'اینترنت اکسپلورر؟!',
            y: 56.33
        }, {
            name: 'کروم؟!',
            y: 24.03,
        }, {
            name: 'فایرفکس؟!',
            y: 10.38
        }, {
            name: 'سفاری؟!',
            y: 4.77
        }, {
            name: 'اوپرا؟!',
            y: 0.91
        }, {
            name: 'دیگر؟!',
            y: 0.2
        }],
    }],

});
```

Completed code see in here online: https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/h4kv0t9v/4/

Comment: your example is not showing any label text except title.. i have the same problem but don't know how to remove this issue...
https://jsfiddle.net/NabiKAZ/h4kv0t9v/4/

Comment: @MuhammadYasir seems this problem there is just on chrome. I work it.

Comment: some body has done for you.. please check it.. Just add useHTML: true to plot options of your chart https://jsfiddle.net/3me9h7k2/

Comment: @MuhammadYasir use `useHTML: true` appears another problem you can see here: http://aplud.com/ja9ak layers on another layes.

Answer (score 0):

you can set direction ltr

Sample:

```html
<div id="container" style="direction: ltr"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the options there is a property: 
"useHtml": true
and if you need in the title you can add style: { direction: rtl }
it works!

Answer (score 0):

only

```
title: {
    text: 'یک نمودار؟!',
    useHTML: true,
},
legend: {
    rtl: true,
},
```

will do the job for you.